# golang: http.get() returns

Tags: function, go

ok so yes im new to golang, but not to coding, I'm a bit confused with the way functions are working with golang, in this 2 weeks I have 9 times out or 10 I had an issue it was related to funtions... I'm no lazy I have search all over for examples to inspire me, but they are all under one main() funtion.
I'm trying to have a http.get in one funtion and many other functions call this funtion everytime we need to use http.get so we dont repeat code over and over.. example:(this is not the actual code)

```
func myfunction(site) []byte {
        resp, err := client.Get(site) // client is because Im tunneling thing on a proxy TOR and had to create some helpers.. but this is working ok.

        return resp
}

func magic(staff) string {
        // do things and create websiteurl with staff and onther contants
        site := myfunction(website)
        contents, err := html.Parse(site.Body)
        //....
        //....
        return  result
}

main() {

        //... stuff happens :)
}
```

well the error is for example because I keep changing things around and getting different errors. or not at all.. but then no result..

cannot use `resp.Body` (type io.ReadCloser) as type `[]byte` in return argument
./gobot.go:71: cannot use site (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to html.Parse:

when I do not get an error that is how I did it the first time the Site.Body
will do nothing when parsing... I put a couple of debug prints to STDOUT and I had results like two sequence of numbers.

so basically how do I return a "result" of my query from one function to the original so it can then be parse and used? 
I hate to repeat code so trying to keep the repetitive code in one function and have it get it call when needed it.

thanks

Comment: `return io.ReadCloser` instead of `return []byte`. I *strongly* suggest running through https://tour.golang.org/ from start to finish.

Comment: You should take more time to write better question and code. The functions' signatures aren't even correct without the argument's type.

Comment: pie it was just a on the fly example to not actually copy paste the real stuff. but thanks to your response below I got it working. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myfunction` has the wrong return type. Instead of `[]byte` it should return `*http.Response`.

```
func myfunction(site string) *http.Response {
        resp, err := client.Get(site) 
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        return resp
}
```

Comment: thanks! that was it :) now I understand this better. thank you.

Comment: @cfernandezlinux please accept it as the answer thanks.